# Using jquery how do I traverse to the name, txtid attributes

Tags: jquery, html

On page load, I parse the following json data

```
{
"status": "success",
"code": 200,
"data": [{
    "txtid": "123",     
    "name": "itemA" 
}, {
    "txtid": "456",     
    "name": "itemB" 
}],
"error": ""
}
```

and generate the following HTML page

I have the following  DOM structure

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" id="Itemlist">
<div class="row" id="details">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default"id="ItemInfo">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
            //some content                                              
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" id="ItemContent">
                    <div class="name"></div>
                    <div class="txtid" hidden></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button id="Button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" role="button">
            Button1
        </button>
        <button id="Button2" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Button2
        </button>
        <button id="Button3" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Button3
        </button>
    </div>                                      
</div>
</div>
```

Basically, I have a **Itemlist** , which contains div **details** (Itemlist can contain multiple details) . When the user clicks on a **Button1** in a particular details div, I want to be able to fetch the corresponding attributes (txtid and name) and do some processing.
In the following **var clickedDOMElement ** gives me the DOM element which I click, but I essentially want to go to the parent's sibling's attributes (txtid and name).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    
$( "*", document.body ).click(function( event ) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var domElement = $( this ).get( 0 );
    var clickedDOMElement= domElement.id;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're assigning the click handler to every element in the DOM? That will be rather slow. A delegated event handler would make more sense if that's the behaviour you want. Also note that if the HTML structure you have in the question is repeated in your page, then you will have invalid HTML as you're repeating the same `id` attributes when they need to be unique

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, it would make more sense to have a dedicated event handler for each button click. But for now, I was only able to come up with this working code. In the Itemlist, for each of the details panel,the id value would differ from the id of another item. I am updating the input json of the item for better clarity.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: @GermanShepherd there is a `.parent()` function in jQuery which gives you the jQuery object for the parent node. There is also a `.prev()` which gives you the element before the current element in the parent. Using those 2 you should be able to the jquery object for the div you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's see what you did not know about: your HTML is invalid, since you can have multiple `div`s having the `id` of `details`. An `id` must be unique in order to ensure the validity of your HTML, therefore, refactor your HTML, or the code which generates it to make sure that whatever can occur more than once will be a `class` instead of an `id`.

And now to the thing which you have asked about: in the `function` you have shown you can use `$(this).parent().siblings("#ItemInfo").find(".txtId")` to find the element we are speaking about, or simply `$(this).closest(".txtId")`. Naturally, after you refactor your HTML, you will need to change the code I have given in accordance to the changes you have done.

Comment: The  id is always unique. I have only provided a sample of my json data. The id attribute is a the primary key in my table, hence it is always unique.

Comment: @GermanShepherd I am not talking about your database. I have no doubt that the id of records in your database are unique. However, the uniqueness of db ids have nothing to do with the validity of your HTML. The validity of your HTML depends on the HTML structure you have. And since you have explicitly said that you might have more than a singe <div class="row" id="details"> item and it is same to assume that you will have id="details" regardless of the db id for all the HTML elements, therefore it is very possible that you will have HTML elements (and not db records) having the same id.

Comment: I understand. I will edit my code such that the class is details. Would that solve the issue?

Comment: @GermanShepherd that part will make sure that you will not get problems due to invalid HTML. For instance, a selector of $("#details") will assume that there is a single match and in contrary with your possible expectation will stop the search there. My second paragraph describes the solution to your actual question. You can use the closest function for that purpose, or a combo of parent, siblings and find.

Comment: That is really helpful. I will try to fetch the id once my HTML structure is corrected.

Comment: @GermanShepherd if you change some ids to classes, for instance you will have class="panel panel-default ItemInfo" instead of id="ItemInfo", then the code in the second paragraph will have to be changed to $(this).parent().siblings(".ItemInfo").find(".txtId"). If the code does not do what we expect, then please create a Fiddle and I will take a look to any possible problems there.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rory McCrossan and @Lajos Arpad noted you have the errors in your HTML.

To find the target element you can use `parents` and `find` functions in button click handler:

```
var parentDetails = $(event.target).parents("[selector for details]");
var txtidElement = parentDetails.find('[selector for txtid element]');
```

Comment: I tried this..  var id=$(domElement).parents().closest().find("#iitemContent").find("#pid").contents; I also tried text() and html(). All of them are undefined. Am I parsing it wrong?

Comment: See an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/90wsoqeo/). I hope it will help you to get the idea